# ios - change navigation bar tint color of 'More' tab

Tags: ios, colors, navigation

I have 7 tabs in my `UITabBar`. `iOS` automatically groups the last 2 tabs into a tab called 'More'. I have set the navigation bar tint color for the 7 tabs in `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

How do I set the color of the navigation bar for the automatically generated 'More' tab?

Comment: How can there be tabs in a navigation bar? "Tabs" sounds like something in a tab bar.

Comment: @matt yes, it's a tab bar. Thanks for editing.

Comment: @pratik i want to set it to the black color

Comment: If it's a tab bar then why does your code talk about `navigationBar`?

Comment: @matt it concerns both the tab bar and the navigation bar.

Comment: A tab bar does not have an "Others" tab. When you say "Others" do you mean "More"?

Comment: @matt Yes maybe its 'More' in English. I am using French as language where it says 'Autre'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access `self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController` to get the navigation controller that appears when the More tab bar item is tapped by the user. Now you can perform modifications and customizations. For example you can change the style of its navigation bar. Example:

```
UINavigationController* more = self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController;
more.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

For more about how to customize what appears when the More tab bar item is tapped, see this section of my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch25.html#_uitabbar

Answer (score 1):

> self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

This line changes the `tintColor` for navigation bar.

From your question, It seems to me (and others, of course) that you have misunderstood `UITabBarController` as `UINavigationController`.

You can find all the information about customizing `UITabBarController` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: No, I want to change the color of the navigation bar at the top. But I have 7 tabs in my tab bar. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the color of   UINavigationController  in AppDelegate.m

```
 UIColor *navBarColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:navBarColor];  
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = navBarColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try apperance (probably in didfinishlaunchingwithoptions in the app delegate).

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7 You can change the colour of the navigation bar, set to non-translucent (yes by default) and change the colour of the navigation title by adding the following into the AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationController *moreController = _tabBarController.moreNavigationController;
moreController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
moreController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
moreController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

Answer (score 0):

for ios 8.0

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```